# Changing the theme with jstree 3.0.0

Tags: jstree

I'm trying to change the theme as follows:

- I copied the contents of the default folder and copied them into a folder called david
- I used replace all in style.css to change instances of .jstree-default with .jstree-david in my editor
- I linked to the david stylesheet
- I added this code to the core object of the jstree config object

  ```
                  "themes": {
                      "name": "david",
                      "dots": true,
                      "icons": true
                  }
  ```

The tree renders with none of the usual dots and icons and click does not expand the root nodes.

How do you create a theme for this new jstree? The style.css file and associated sprites are different from the version 1 themes I used to work with.

Are there any themes available already created for jstree 3.0.0?

UPDATE:
So used to getting my information from StackOverflow, I was delighted to get [help](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jstree/f_HUf0DmUjY) on this issue directly from jstree's author in a very timely manner.

Comment: I am curious about this too...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Do your remember include your css file successfully?
I use the following code to change the theme to dark. Hope to help you.

```
$('#jstree_demo_div').jstree({
        'core' : {
             "themes": {
                "name": "default-dark",
                "dots": true,
                "icons": true
            },
            ...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/images/jstree_themes/default-dark/style.min.css" />
```